# Calculating Largest Sum from N lists of Numbers taking one element from each list

Tags: algorithm, np

Problem Statement: I have N lists of numbers. I have to take one element from each list and cannot take more than one number from any list. Calculate the maximum sum. 
I think this is an NP-Hard problem. If it is indeed an NP-Hard problem, what assumption could make it a polynomial complexity problem? 
This is a real industry problem.

Comment: Why don't you sort all the list and pick last element from each list, that will give you maximum sum.

Comment: Maybe you are overthinking this.

Comment: I get the feeling that there is important information that you're not telling us. As stated, the problem seems trivially easy: find the maximum number in each list, and add them together. Are there restrictions that prevent you from doing that?

Answer (score 3):

Take the maximum of each list, and sum it.

in python:

```
data = [[1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [0, -1, 2]]
result = sum(max(sub) for sub in data)

# -> 7
```

complexity = `O(n)`, where `n` is the total number of elements in the sublists